# Obtain IP address logging data from firmware? other non-hdd memory?

Tags: networking, ip, logging

Is there a way to find a history of internet sites (IP addresses) a laptop / computer has communicated with, without having the hard disk installed? In other words, is this data logged into firmware or any non-volatile memory other than the HDD?

A way in which this could conceivably be possible is if the network chipset had some non-volatile memory of which a portion were used for this purpose, or the motherboard itself.

Comment: Has someone understood the question? How can a laptop works "with without having the hard disk installed"?

Comment: If there is no storage device then nothing can be logged.

Comment: @duDE Presumably the hard disk was removed by a person wanting to conceal their activities, or the OP has removed it to conceal theirs.

Comment: @dude This calls for a new invention.... LoL

Answer (score 1):

No it is not. A computer does not store connection information anywhere apart from its non-volatile storage. It is however possible (to a certain extend) to retrieve that data from other sources which may include but are not limited to:

- Routers
- Gateways
- Proxy servers